# Data transfer with permissions (AD) from windows to linux

Tags: linux, windows, rsync, file-transfer

good day friends,
I have a problem with the transfer of data (files and folders) from a windows server (integrated with active directory) to a linux server. The active directory delivers permissions, both at the user level and at the group level, and requires that, when they go to the linux server, they remain, as they will continue to be accessed by windows machines.
The data is transferred without problem (rsync). The problem occurs with the permissions of the files and folders.
The command executed from linux is:

```
mount -t cifs  //192.168.36.115/compartido1 /mnt -o username=administrator,work`enter code here`group=testlab

rsync -aArz /mnt/wcordero/* /gpfs/gpfscl1/compras/
```

//192.168.36.115/compartido1  = Old NAS Windows

/mnt/wcordero/* = Path to transfer

/gpfs/gpfscl1/compras/wcordero = Final path

[To the Left Windows. To the right linux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJWW8.png)

I have tried with the options of rsync -p, -A and the result is the same.

I appreciate your collaboration

ps: I have used robocopy in windows cmd and it meets the need, but the performance is not optimal (due to the amount of data) and I want to do it from linux.

Comment: rsync doesn't "know" Windows ACLs, so can't replicate them directly. If this is for some archival purpose, you can always store the ACLs separately (if you have some way to save the ACLs, e.g. via icacls or something similar). If you need live access to the files, you'll have to do it via robocopy, I'm afraid.